# Unhelpful "Could not get screen information" in gnome-control-center display - 15.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, xorg, display

I'm getting a very unhelpful error attempting to open the screen display preferences on Ubuntu deskop 15.10.

After some research I found that it could be related to dual displays.  I had an older CRT monitor plugged into the onboard video port, so I decided to unplug it and restart X using `sudo service lightdm restart` but it had no effect AFAIK.

There's almost no log output that I can tell, dmesg doesn't seem to indicate anything, and using `watch find /var/log -cmin 1` only indicates that `Xorg.0.log` is being modified, here's what I found using a `tail -n0 -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  2519.885] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[  2519.885] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.885] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE228 (DFP-0): connected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE228 (DFP-0):     Internal TMDS
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE228 (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: disconnected
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: Internal TMDS
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  2519.917] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

I don't really know what I'm doing here, but Googling suggests XRANDR could be a factor in this puzzle, so I ran it and this is what it output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I also tried running `sudo Xorg -configure :1` and it may have revealed something interesting but I do not know either way (I subjectively chose to trim-off the uninteresting parts, let me know if that would be helpful):

```
(++) Using config file: "/home/jonathan/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

This was working fine before I installed the nVidia driver for my card (coincidentally that is when I decided to plug the other monitor in the other onboard port).  I have the nVidia 352.41 driver installed.